# Public transport drive times in Europe/ Germany possible with Deutsche Bahn?

Tags: arcpy, distance, routing, api, transportation

**Background:**

There are many data sources for calculating drive times for driving, walking or cycling, for example Google Maps DistanceMatrix, ESRIS WebServices (no bicycle at the moment) etc. They all have there advantages and disadvantages but with a little effort you can get the needed information.

But, on the one hand, there seems to be no comprehensive data source for public transport information in Europe and especially in Germany. I have tried some alternatives like Google Maps DistanceMatrix - problem here is that only some parts of Germany support public transport outside the long-distance traffic - or OpenStreetMap - partially incomplete, outdated or wrong information.

On the other hand you have a mighty service from the Deutsche Bahn, like `http://www.fahrplanauskunft.de/bin/query.exe/d`. This database is not limited to their own "products" like Deutsche Bahn trains but also shows local public transport information or information of their regional competitors. On top of all, their information is not limited to the country border of germany but comprehensively cover large parts of Europe.

**Question:**

What options are there to use their information in ArcGIS/ ArcPy/ Python/ etc. for calculating drive times from one point to an other?

I found a project which also want to participate on their information (OpenBahn API), but this project has stoped. Are there any comparable APIs or possible opportunities (like json, http get etc.) to use this information without a manual search on one of the websites of Deutsche Bahn? At the beginning my first goal is only to send one information like starting point, ending point and arrival/ departure time and receive a computer readable answer like duration or maybe the frequency of daily connections.

Comment: This data is state owned (Germany) but copyrighted so cannot be used correct? There is http://www1.deutschebahn.com/dbhackathon-en/hackathon/dbhackathon3.html

Answer (score 2):

The data is fully owned by DB but there is a gray area. And some projects/apps like Öffi are tolerated from DB but they just query the closed API.

Have a look into two projects [openPlanB](https://github.com/MichaelKreil/openPlanB) and [public-transport-enabler](https://github.com/schildbach/public-transport-enabler) (latter one is used for Öffi)